# Display and hide a set of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

Previously I asked how to get my show/hide function work and thanks to your help this solved my problem. Now I am only stuck at the point to show a set of DIVS.
To be more accurate I have 4 divs, all with a unique ID and CLASS. These DIVS are showed by selecting an option in a list.

When a user chooses DIV_1, then DIV_1 shows. The JQuery part I use selects a DIV by there unique ID and Class. Only now I try to combine some. So when a user chooses option 5 for example DIV_1 AND DIV_2 shows and option 6 DIV_3 and DIV_4. shows. Only now I am stuck because I show a DIV on the unique ID, so I can't combine it. Does anyone has an idea how to accomplish this?

```
$('#DIV_1').change(function() {
            $('.DIV_1').slideUp("fast");
            $('#' + $(this).val()).slideDown("fast");
        });
```

Comment: post your working code with option and where is your Previously asked question how should we know in Previous question  what you done.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign more than one class to an object. This will make it easier to select subsets. For example, now you can select .top .middle or .bottom in this example. You could apply another class to all of them as well in order to be able to show/hide all of them at once, for example.

```
<div class="div_1 top"></div>
<div class="div_2 top"></div>
<div class="div_3 middle"></div>
<div class="div_4 middle"></div>
<div class="div_5 bottom"></div>
<div class="div_6 bottom"></div>
```